# Cannot find the Slack App we created in the list of apps created inside "Your Apps"

Tags: slack, slack-api

We built a Slack app a few months ago and set everything up except getting it approved and listed on the Slack App Marketplace.

We have been doing improvements on it but all have been on the bot side and have not touched our configuration within Slack.

Now, we feel like we can submit it to the marketplace but cannot seem to find our app in "https://api.slack.com/apps/" where we're supposed to find our app.

At first we thought we must have created our app using a different defunct workspace but upon checkin our app inside our current workspace, we get the tag:

> This app was created by a member of your workspace, *****.The permissions this app requests have not been reviewed by Slack.

Thus, we're sure it was created with this current workspace. But, https://api.slack.com/apps/ is empty. And we are only prompted to make a new app.

I cannot be sure but there might be possibility that the app was created using an account that is not part our workspace anymore. Could this be the case? If so, what are we supposed to do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Make sure you're on https://api.slack.com/apps/ on the account of the owner

Comment: @Samathingamajig are you talking about the owner of the app or the owner of the workspace? What are we supposed to do if the app owner isn't part of the workspace anymore?

Comment: If the app owner is not longer part of the workspace you should contact Slack's platform support team at feedback@slack.com and they will help you through an app ownership transfer.